# Could WebWorkers be used to calculate word frequencies on a very long page?

Tags: javascript, frequency, web-worker

I'm writing a browser-based (Javascript and jQuery) linguistic analysis tool that extracts text from HTML and then extracts linguistic units such as  sentences, words, and so on.

To import text, a PHP backend spiders a given URL and sanitizes the resulting HTML. Then that HTML is inserted into a `div#container` in the interface, something like this:

[image]

I have run into some difficulties when the source HTML page is very long. Reading and inserting such a page into the interface's `DOM` doesn't seem to cause problems (though it takes a while).

But running a word frequency algorithm over the spidered content is very slow if the page is long. If the page is approaches 100K words, say, it will pretty much bring things to a grinding halt.

So, I see a few options:

1. Change the PHP spider so that it will truncate the source document or subdivide it into multiple documents
2. Change the word frequency algorithm so that it's less exact, and samples the word distribution rather than recording it completely
3. Try out this new-fangled Web Worker thing to see if I can distribute the calculation across multiple background processes.

It would appear to me that (3) is just the word of thing that Web Workers is designed to do. I'm imagining splitting the spidered content into chunks, and then assigning one Web Worker to each chunk. The word frequency profile of each chunk can be returned from the Web Worker, and then summed up and rendered to the chart.

Before I attempt this, I was hoping I could get a sanity check from other folks here who may have worked with Web Workers before. For one thing, I'm wondering if splitting up the contents of `div#container` efficiently will be an issue -- I suppose it would involve some sort of traversal through the DOM tree under `div#container`.

Answer (score 0):

Web workers would certainly be a viable option, but the trade-off is that you can't guarantee cross-browser compatibility. It might be worth breaking the content up into chunks and making use of setTimeout, to see if that makes a difference. It will prevent the browser from locking up, and would prevent any long-running script warnings from occurring. Nicholas Zakas wrote a blog entry about this sort of thing a while ago: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/13/speed-up-your-javascript-part-1/

The method he suggests is:

```
function chunk(array, process, context){
  var items = array.concat();   //clone the array
  setTimeout(function(){
    var item = items.shift();
    process.call(context, item);

    if (items.length > 0){
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
    }
  }, 100);
}
```

Personally, I don't think the delay of 100ms is necessary; I've seen it stated elsewhere that you can put a delay of 0ms, as this is enough to interrupt a long running script, and prevent the browser from locking up.

If this doesn't improve things, then yes, Web Workers would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I'll give this approach a try and see how it goes. I'll reply here...

One thing I wonder about is the use of `callee` here -- isn't that deprecated?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is. You could always use a named function instead - so `setTimeout(function wrap(){ ... });` in the outer `setTimeout` call, and then just call `wrap` instead of `arguments.callee`